# Getting and serializing the state of dynamically created python instances to a relational model

Tags: python, metaprogramming, pickle

I'm developing a framework of sorts. I'm providing a base class, that will be subclassed by other developers to add behavior to the system. The instances of those classes will have attributes that my framework doesn't necessarily expect, except by inspecting those instances' `__dict__`.  To make things even more interesting, some of those classes can be created dynamically, at any time.

I'd like some things to be handled by the framework, namely, I will need to persist those instances, display their attribute values to the user, and let her search/filter instances using those values.

I have to use a relational database. I know there are some decent python OO database out there, but unfortunately they're not an option in this case.

I'm not looking for a full-blown ORM too...  and it may not even be an option, given that some of the classes can be created dynamically.

So, my question is, **what state of a python instance do I need to serialize to ensure that I can deserialize it later on? Is it enough to look at `__dict__`, or are there other private attributes that I should be using?**

Pickling the instances is not enough, because I'll need to unpickle them to search/filter the attribute values, and I'm afraid it's too much data to do it in-memory (instead of letting the database do it).

Comment: You might consider requiring those developers to implement `serialize()` and `deserialize()` methods on their subclasses, which would simplify your own problem.

Comment: Serialization is mostly a solved problem. Unless you have a very good reason, just use an ORM. And please don't try to do this without *any* cooperation of the subclasses - you won't get very far. Some declarations are required to do this kind of stuff (unless you want to wind up with something like pickle - quick to get started, but you have zero control over the backend, it can break in various ways, and *still* requires some cooperation if you want anything fancy). There's a reason basically every Python ORM require you to declare `member = db.DataType()`.

Comment: @delnan in this case, it would be ok to assume that all properties are strings, or string dictionaries

Comment: I've added a requirement that I hadn't realized was that important (but in fact is): some of the classes can be created dynamically, so I expect that "traditional" ORMs won't be able to deal with them easily... we still need to bind the classes to the respective tables somehow, right?

Comment: @FilipeCorreia I don't know what a "traditional" ORM is, but all class creation in python is in fact dynamic, so that is not an issue.

Comment: @delnan as to why I think an ORM is not a good fit for this case, I've updated the question and tried to make it more clear. The thing is, some of the classes are created dynamically, but I the database schema isn't supposed to change after the software is installed

Answer (score 1):

Just use an ORM. This is what they are for.

What you are proposing to do is create your own half-assed ORM on your own time. Save your time for your own code that does things, and use the effort other people put for free into solving this problem for you.

Note that all class creation in python is "dynamic" - this is not an issue, for, well, anything at all. In fact, if you are assembling classes programmatically, it is probably slightly easier with an ORM, because they provide reifications of fields.

In the worst case, if you really do need to store your objects in a fake nosql-type schema, you will still only have to write your own backend driver if you use an existing ORM, rather than coding the whole stack yourself. (As it happens, you're not the first person to face this - solutions exist. Goole "python orm store dynamically created models" and "sqlalchemy store dynamically created models")

Candidates include:

- Django ORM
- SQLAlchemy
- Some others you can find by googling "Python ORM".

Comment: Thks for the answer. I've updated the question with a bit more info on why I'm trying to avoid ORMs...

Comment: @FilipeCorreia As long as you can dynamically create classes which inherit from the ORM base class (or however else the ORM hooks into classes), you can still use an ORM.

Comment: You mean, to let the ORM figure out which db tables it needs to create? I don't see it an option in this case, because I can create additional tables, but I can't let the orm create new tables as the system gets used and new classes are created (I don't completely control this database, and the schema is not supposed to change dynamically). What I had in mind was to have a "Class" table, an "Instance" table, a "Attribute" table, and so on. ORMs usually take an approach in which each class is (roughly) mapped to a table.

Comment: @FilipeCorreia Now you are speculating about the options that an ORM might offer you. It sounds like you are saying that you expect to create the tables "by hand"; in that case, I see even less of a reason why you can't write a new class per table when you create each table.

Comment: @FilipeCorreia Its clear that there are more details you are not telling us. Without that, we can't recommend an ORM or how to use it. However, there are also NoSQL backends for python ORMs, which again do not require a store with a defined schema. Go and look at what is out there, then come back with a question with reference to the existing solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear. I know a few ORMs, but not all, of course. I guess you may say that I'm speculating about the options that an ORM might offer me, but only because I don't know any that supports this use case. Let me try to explain better; I think it can be summed up like this: a) I can create tables by hand, but it must be a fixed schema, I can't let the system create new tables; b) The classes are not fixed, the system can dynamically create classes as it gets used. Can you point me to an code example of a ORM that supports this use case?

Comment: I know about NoSQL databases. In this case, unfortunately, I must use a relational DB, that is already be used by different parts of the system.

Comment: @FilipeCorreia Yes, I can, because I spent 2 minutes googling the topic. It's time for you to do that as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9931/discussion-between-filipe-correia-and-marcin)